# Python pandas read_table converts zero to NaN

Tags: python, pandas

Say I have the following file `test.txt`:

```
Aaa Bbb
Foo 0
Bar 1
Baz NULL
```

(The separator is actually a tab character, which I can't seem to input here.)
And I try to read it using pandas (0.10.0):

```
In [523]: pd.read_table("test.txt")
Out[523]:
   Aaa  Bbb
0  Foo  NaN
1  Bar    1
2  Baz  NaN
```

Note that the zero value in the first column has suddenly turned into NaN! I was expecting a DataFrame like this:

```
   Aaa   Bbb
0  Foo     0
1  Bar     1
2  Baz   NaN
```

What do I need to change to obtain the latter? I suppose I could use `pd.read_table("test.txt", na_filter=False)` and subsequently replace 'NULL' values with NaN and change the column dtype. Is there a more straightforward solution?

Comment: If you try to read "Foo 0\n Bar 0\n" do they both turn into NaN, or is it unique to the first data row.

Comment: All zeros in that column turn into NaN. This happens as soon as the column contains one NA value (like 'NULL').

Comment: Does it still occur if your restrict your type to int with dtype?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is issue [#2599](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/2599), "read_csv treats zeroes as nan if column contains any nan", which is now closed.  I can't reproduce in my development version:

```
In [27]: with open("test.txt") as fp:
   ....:     for line in fp:
   ....:         print repr(line)
   ....:         
'Aaa\tBbb\n'
'Foo\t0\n'
'Bar\t1\n'
'Baz\tNULL\n'

In [28]: pd.read_table("test.txt")
Out[28]: 
   Aaa  Bbb
0  Foo    0
1  Bar    1
2  Baz  NaN

In [29]: pd.__version__
Out[29]: '0.10.1.dev-f7f7e13'
```

Comment: That explains why I don't see this bug either! :) Awesome.

Comment: Thanks! Yes, this seems to be the problem: I'm using 64bit Windows as well.

Comment: I still think this is the issue, but here's something weird: `pd.read_table("test.txt")` and `pd.read_table("test.txt", sep="\t")` exhibit the bug, but `pd.read_table("test.txt", sep="\t+")` or `pd.read_table("test.txt", sep="\s+")` don't. I'll check the development version later.

Comment: @RafG: which parsing approach is used can depend upon whether or not the delimiter triggers the regex path or not.  I had an issue the other day (now fixed) where using `sep=" "` gave a completely different answer from that given by `sep=r"\s+"`.

Comment: Yes-- I fixed this bug. We're going to try to get the next release out next week-- use the dev version for now if you can.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_table("14256839_input.txt", sep=" ", na_values="NULL")
print df
print df.dtypes
```

This gives me

```
   Aaa  Bbb
0  Foo    0
1  Bar    1
2  Baz  NaN
Aaa     object
Bbb    float64
```